# Mongodb failed to connect to server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Im getting this error about not my application not being able to connect to mongo after i run "nodemon index.js":

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost localhost:27017]
at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/Dakota/Projects/2018-Udemy-Bootcamp/node-mongo-project/todos_api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/Dakota/Projects/2018-Udemy-Bootcamp/node-mongo-project/todos_api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Dakota/Projects/2018-Udemy-Bootcamp/node-mongo-project/todos_api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

My code is as follows:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/todo-api';
mongoose.set('debug', true);

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => {
  console.log("Database connection is active");
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});

module.exports.Todo = require('./todo');
```

I have started up mongod in the terminal.

This issue happens at home on my network but if i go to the coffee shop down the street it will connect. I have read a few things about Firewalls causing issues and IP Addresses and have tried to the best of my knowledge to adjust those two things but i cannot seem to figure this issue out still.

Any insight on how i could resolve this?

Comment: Are your database is running?? What is the output of `service mongod status` in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

At first, check if your mongodb service is running correctly.

Also you could replace **localhost** with **127.0.0.1** like this:

```
// connect to database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/todo-api', { useNewUrlParser: true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log(`MongoDB connected!`);
});
```

**EDIT:** I found [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#replicaset-hostnames) form mongoose doc:

> MongoDB replica sets rely on being able to reliably figure out the domain name for each member. On Linux and OSX, the MongoDB server uses the output of the `hostname` command to figure out the domain name to report to the replica set. This can cause confusing errors if you're connecting to a remote MongoDB replica set running on a machine that reports its `hostname` as `localhost`:

```
// Can get this error even if your connection string doesn't include
// `localhost` if `rs.conf()` reports that one replica set member has
// `localhost` as its host name.
failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

> If you're experiencing a similar error, connect to the replica set using the mongo shell and run the `rs.conf()` command to check the host names of each replica set member. [Follow this page's instructions to change a replica set member's host name](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/#change-hostnames-while-maintaining-replica-set-availability).

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! Any insight as to why this could have caused issues for me? Side note this worked with both node and nodemon